# CMAKE include_directories

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

I am trying to link my library with some other library `lib1` using `CMAKE 2.8`. It should be said it's on Windows.

In `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
add_library(mylib ${sources})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib1/include)
target_link_libraries(mylib ${lib1_path})
```

But compiler says that some `#include <lib1/foo.h>` in my library is unresolved, maybe because there is no `-I.../lib1/include` command-line parameter for `gcc`.

**UPDATE**: It should be said that compiler is complaining when compiling TESTS not the `mylib`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the following:

1. Does the path `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib1/include/lib1/foo.h` exist?
2. Quote (`"`) the path passed to `include_directories`, otherwise you may be passing several paths when it is split by spaces
3. Try running `make VERBOSE=1` to see exactly what options are being passed to gcc

Answer (score 7):

Try to move `include_directories()` invokation before add_library.

`add_library()` instructs CMake to compile your sources into library using current set of compiler flags. Altering these flags after compiling do not have any effect. CMake language is not declarative.

Comment: It didn't helped :-( The _test_ using `mylib` still doesn't know about the `lib1`.

Comment: It should have helped... I guess we need more information to figure out what's going on. You didn't mention any *test* in your question. What does the CMakeLists code related to the test look like?